# Get users query makes the site loading time too big?

Tags: wp-query, user-roles, users, views

I'm trying to get the top 10 users in (specific roles) by the highest post views, but this code makes the site loading time too big, and I don't know why!

I'm highly appreciated your help.

```
<?php 

    global $wp_query;
    $topuser = array();

    $args = array(
        'role__in'     => array('contributor', 'author')
     ); 
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    $users = $user_query->get_results();

    foreach ( $users as $userss ) {       

    $counter = 0;

    $args = array(
      'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ) ),
      'author' => $userss->ID,
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'cat' => '3'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    foreach ( $query as $post ){
            $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ));
            $counter += $views;
        }
        $topuser[] = array( 
        'id' => $userss->ID, 
        'viewz' => $counter
        );
        wp_reset_query();
    }

    function sortViewssz($a, $b) {
        return $b['viewz'] - $a['viewz'];
    }
    usort($topuser, 'sortViewssz'); // sort the array
    $output = array_slice($topuser, 0, 10); // slice the array by limit 10

    foreach ($output as $user){

        //display users name..etc

    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't know why people here gives vote down instead of giving help or even to tell me what i did wrong? It's just a question about code making the site loading, And I just need to know why! Anyways, Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but this code makes the site loading time too big, and I don't know
>   why!

I think that is just because you are getting quite a lot of stuff from the database with your code. Escpecially if your code runs on every single page load.

Here's my suggestions,

**Extra parameters to `WP_Query` to potentially make the query more efficient.**

```
$args = array(
  'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => '1 week ago' ) ),
  'author' => $userss->ID,
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'cat' => '3',

  'no_found_rows' => true, // "useful when pagination is not needed", from https://10up.github.io/Engineering-Best-Practices/php/
  'fields' => 'ids', // no need for all post data if get_post_meta is only what the post data is used for
  'update_post_term_cache' => false, // not needed if you're not using terms in your loop 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

As a personal experience, I've noticed that sometimes it makes sense to write your own `sql`statement and use it with `$wpdb->prepare/get_results` to get stuff out of the database faster.

**Remove `wp_reset_query();` from `foreach` loop**

This probably just a minor tweak, but looking at the `wp_reset_query` Codex entry,

> Calling wp_reset_query is not necessary after using WP_Query or
>   get_posts as these don't modify the main query object. Instead use
>   wp_reset_postdata

And I don't think you don't need to use `wp_reset_postdata()` either as you're not affecting the global `$post` variable.

**Use transient cache**

If new contributors and authors are not added very frequently, you could store `$user_query->get_results();` into a transient, with sensible expiration time or refresh when new one is added, to skip doing `WP_User_Query` every single time.

If it fits your setup and situation, perhaps you could save `$query = new WP_Query( $args );` for each user as a transient with expiration time of one day. Then update the transient with a cronjob, WP or a real one, daily.

If the view count doesn't need to be exactly real-time, then perhaps you could consider saving the total result from `$counter += $views;` into a transient (maybe with a expiration time of one hour?) too.

So instead of querying every time, every post over the last week, for every user with correct role, you would be getting these with three `get_transient` calls.

**Minor tweak to user sorting**

I'm not sure, if this has any real effect on the performance, but I'm adding this at least as a curiosity.

```
// Instead of this
$topuser[] = array( 
  'id' => $userss->ID, 
  'viewz' => $counter
);

// You could do this
$topuser[$userss->ID] = $counter:

// So you can then use arsort() which
// sorts an associative array in descending order, according to the value:
arsort($topuser);

// Create also a helper array to go along with $topuser
$users_by_id[$userss->ID] = $userss;
// From which you can get user data with ID in your foreach ($output as $user) loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the amazing explanation!